# d3 force-directed layout expands on reheat

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider any d3 force-directed animation, such as:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288

Load that graph and let the nodes settle down so that they are not moving.  Hover your mouse over an orange node and let the mouse be still.  Click and do nothing else.  You will see all the nodes move inwards a little and then expand back to normal.

I do not like that unnecessary movement and I need to remove it.

I believe it has to do with the graph being "reheated" (see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout
), which sets the alpha parameter to 0.1.  Specifically, I see the unnecessary movement occur immediately after any of the following.

1. a new node is added to the graph
2. a node is deleted from the graph
3. `force.drag()` is called.

What exactly causes this "unnecessary movement", and how can I disable it? (without disabling node dragging)

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3.js static force layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021663/d3-js-static-force-layout)

Comment: The force layout is made for exactly this recalculations of the nodes positions. Your can set the nodes to a specific position, if you really want it there. Or after maybe 3 seconds you set the nodes to fixed. It's up to what you wanna have at the end.

Comment: @kwoxer This is not a duplicate of the other question.  This question is *not* about how the nodes behave when the graph initializes.  I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Okay then why not just fix the nodes?

Comment: @kwoxer I do not think you have read my question carefully.  I think I have described it clearly.

Comment: Isn't this what your looking for? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

Comment: @StaceyBurns No.  Try clicking and holding on any node (in your url) without moving the mouse.  Then move the mouse just one pixel.  Regardless of the direction you move the mouse, you will see all the nodes move inward slightly towards it, and then back outwards.  On the other hand, when a node's position is fixed and you double-click it to release it, you will see no such perturbation.

Comment: @marecroft ok i see what you mean. The other nodes move with the movement direction of selected node but move a bit forward then back a little. Say you move the node 1px to the left, the child's will move 2px towards the node then 1px back. Is it the case you only want it to move the 1px without it doing the sort of bounce it does?

Comment: @StaceyBurns Yes!  The other nodes move *towards* the selected node, then back a little.  Say you move the node 1px, then ALL the other nodes will move a few px towards it and then back.  I'm glad somebody finally sees what I'm talking about :)  And yes, I do not want that bounce.  It is as-if the clicked node momentarily had a larger charge.  I don't want that because it is distracting to users navigating my graph.

Comment: @mareoraft it looks like it comes from the force.resume function setting the alpha to 0.1. This function is called during the dragmove. I set it to 0.01 and it reduces the bounce on the move `force.resume = function() {
    return force.alpha(0.01);
  };`  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkwnd7zg/1/). Not too sure if this is what you are after but if it is I'll add it an an answer with more detail.

Comment: @StaceyBurns This is on the right track.  But changing alpha in this way has undesirable effects, such as making the graph freeze before settling down.  There is some internal function that makes alpha decrease ("cooling the graph").  Perhaps we could override that function to make alpha decrease more slowly.  Also there is an internal cut-off at 0.005 where the graph freezes.  Perhaps we could lower the cut-off.  I have yet to find the source code that controls this stuff.

Comment: @StaceyBurns Lowering alpha lessens the bounce, but I feel like this is just mitigating the issue.  We have yet to find the heart of the issue.

Comment: @mareoraft, I added an answer to explain what I have found so far. It may not be the final answer but I think it can get us somewhere!

Comment: note to self: one solution is to make alpha constant, and then manually "pause" the graph instead of setting alpha to 0 to freeze it.

Comment: I think the best solution may be to alter how alpha is used when the forces are calculated in `forceAccumulate` and in `force.tick`.  Although all the alterations I've tried so far cause the graph to expand or collapse indefinitely.  I still don't understand what exactly alpha does within the `force.tick` function, for example, in the line `l = alpha * strengths[i] * ((l = Math.sqrt(l)) - distances[i]) / l;
`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when `force.resume()` is fired, the alpha value jumps from 0 to 0.1.  By easing alpha up more slowly, we can cover up the "unnecessary movement".

I am still open to other ideas and solutions.

old function:

```
force.resume = function() {
  return force.alpha(.1);
};
```

replacement function:

```
force.resume = function() {
  var alpha = force.alpha()
  if( alpha < 0.005 ){ alpha = 0.0055 }
  else if( alpha < 0.11 ){ alpha += 0.0006 }
  return force.alpha(alpha);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior comes mainly from the alpha. The alpha function within d3:

```
force.alpha = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return alpha;
  x = +x;
  if (alpha) {
    if (x > 0) alpha = x; else alpha = 0;
  } else if (x > 0) {
    event.start({
      type: "start",
      alpha: alpha = x
    });
    d3.timer(force.tick);
  }
  return force;
};
```

So when alpha is called, it starts the tick event if greater than 0

Within the tick event, at the very beginning, you can see the cut off that is causing the 'freeze' you mentioned:

```
if ((alpha *= .99) < .0005) {
         event.end({
           type: "end",
           alpha: alpha = 0
         });
         return true;
       }
```

Now, if we look at the dragmove, it calls the resume function:

```
function dragmove(d) {
      d.px = d3.event.x, d.py = d3.event.y;
      force.resume();
    }
```

which calls the alpha function with a value of 0.1:

```
 force.resume = function() {
      return force.alpha(.1);
    };
```

To stop the jump and also the freeze at 0.0005, I don't see myself any public function you can use.

I have an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/staceyburnsy/74ugr5tv/1/) that removed the code from the tick function that causes the freezing and also changed the resume function to start at a smaller alpha.

I believe this gives the result your looking for but of course, I wouldn't really advise customizing the library.

Maybe someone knows how to override the tick function without having to modify the source.

Comment: I think I will have to customize the library.  I'm going to see if I can figure what exactly `event.start` is, and how it relates to `force.start`.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting past the line `var candidates = neighbors[i], j = -1, l = candidates.length, x;` in the library.  It is using `i` from outside the function.  Also, if no input positions are supplied, does it give a random number?

Comment: This function is only called if your x and y values are not numbers, from this function in the start method: `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

      o = nodes[i];
    
      if (isNaN(o.x)) o.x = position("x", w);
      if (isNaN(o.y)) o.y = position("y", h);
      if (isNaN(o.px)) o.px = o.x;
      if (isNaN(o.py)) o.py = o.y;
    
    }`  The `i` is the `i` from this method

Comment: Thanks for all you help!

Answer (score 0):

in

```
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

You could move the update to the children open only

```
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
      update();
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }

  }
}
```

so a node without children (orange) will not be updated on click.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The question is not specific to trees.

Comment: s/he wanted to get rid of the update when the orange circles are clicked. It does just that, in swapping 2 lines of code. How much simpler can it be? While the voted answer is ncie and complete, it suggests doing a lot of edits to the core library and I don't think this is what the OP wants to do!

Comment: I am the OP and I am fine with editing the library if it solves the problem.  I did not want to get rid of the update, but rather I wanted to prevent the unnecessary perturbation or spasm that the nodes make when the graph changes from a still position to a moving position (which occurs when the graph is still and then you drag a node in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr833scv/)).  If you are confident your answer does this, please fork the fiddle and link back to your solution here.

Comment: OP asked a question about this specific code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 and now links to some 3000+ lines of code that barely anything to do with the original. I answered the question about the above code. 
An Orange node is a leaf node. A click does nothing to it but make it sizzle. My answer removes the update on orange nodes and gets rid of it as asked. But obviously OP is working on a very different fork now so who cares...