# How to draw nodes in d3 force layout with same sequence on every refresh?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I've used force layout to draw a graph using the d3.v3 library. I have taken [this](http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116) example for reference.

The graph is working fine. currently, when every time I refresh the graph the position of each node is changed.

Is there is any way to store the order of nodes in force layout? So, it will draw in the same sequence.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021663/d3-js-static-force-layout

Comment: @Gilsha - Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for the same result as per question in the suggested link. But in my case number of nodes is not fixed. So how do I predefined the position of nodes in JSON?

Comment: I would suggest plotting the whole graph once using the force layout with the required gravity and extract data bonded to the chart dynamically with the node positions.